# WebPack - Assets and Images disappearing in stylesheets

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack, and this is my first time using it. I've done tons of digging on the issue, but it seems all I can find is scattered information because the root cause is all different, with these loaders.

Anyways, I'm struggling pulling in my assets through the file loaders. I'm using a boiler plate, the React Starter Kit by Kriasoft. It's using webpack for a bundler.

here is an image of the file structure: http://grab.by/NqqA

Currently, I'm storing my images in the public folder, /public/images. I'm using postCSS in my src/componenets/ folder, and referencing the images by ./public/images/title.jpg in my stylesheet.

When I save and build the app, the images are transcoded but not loading.

Example, header.scss in /src/componenets/header/header.scss is trying to pull an image in as a background:

Header.scss

```
@import '../variables.scss';

$brand-color: #61dafb;

.header {
    background: url('./public/images/inverse.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding: 1.5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Once the app builds, it copies the public assets folder into the build folder. The image has this path in chrome inspector: http://grab.by/Nqrq

However, Webpack isn't understanding how to pull these in. I'm currently using the webpack.config.js file that comes in the React Starter Kit repo, which can be viewed here:

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js

I can't figure out what is going on here, a lot of the issues I've read on their support threads involve the source loaders, though I haven't seen anything similar to my problem.

If anyone has any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it, and I'm sure others will, too.

Thanks

Comment: Are the images files being placed in your `build` folder at all? Can you share an image/overview of what files are copied to build?

Comment: The images are being copied into the build folder.

Comment: The images are being copied into the build folder. Here is an image of the build folder with the images inside.

http://grab.by/NqKK

I'm thinking it has to do with the source maping, or the file/css loaders. I'm using the default out of the box repo from https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit, though i've added a few new images because I'm trying to start the UI and having trouble with using the background: url(/path/to/image) property. At some points, I was seeing my image load, and then disappear.

Comment: Then it sounds more like an error in how static files are served. I assume you use node/express? Do you have a dev and prod config/build? What does your server file look like?

Comment: yes, i do. I can show you that right now actually..

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/master/src/server.js

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm fighting wth the same issue.